# Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script to follow button

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am trying to trigger a button on a dynamically generated page having the follow source:

```
<button class="pt-button" type="button">Restart</button>
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Any pointers?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    waitForKeyElements("#button.pt-button:contains('Restart')", clickButtonAfterDelay);

    function clickButtonAfterDelay (jNode) {
    if (document.readyState != "complete")  return true;
        setTimeout (triggerMouseEvent, 2222, jNode[0], "click");
    }

    function triggerMouseEvent (jNode) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
})();
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser console? ... Also it should be: `setTimeout (triggerMouseEvent, 2222, jNode);` .

Comment: I don't see errors in the browser console, but Restart action is not triggered. Is there a better way to debug apart from the dev console in Chrome?

Comment: Did you try that line of code I corrected?  Also Chrome does have a debugger and you can set Tampermonkey to debug-mode and step through your code if you must.

Comment: Yes, tried with the setTimeout change, still doesn't work